# Transition dipole matrix element

Tags: density-functional-theory, band-structure, solid-state-physics, periodic-system

When doing DFT calculations of periodic solids, from either [$\mathbf{k \cdot p}$ perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C2%B7p_perturbation_theory) or simply using the trick $\mathbf{r} \rightarrow i\partial_{\mathbf{k}}$, one can obtain
$$
\langle \psi_{c\mathbf{k}}|\partial_\mathbf{k} \psi_{v\mathbf{k}}\rangle = -i \langle \psi_{c\mathbf{k}}| \mathbf{r} | \psi_{v\mathbf{k}}\rangle = -i \langle u_{c\mathbf{k}}|\mathbf{r}| u_{v\mathbf{k}}\rangle \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
where $\mathbf{r}$ is the position operator, $\psi_{c\mathbf{k}}=u_{c\mathbf{k}}e^{i\mathbf{k \cdot r}}$ is the Bloch wave function, $c,v$ for conduction and valence bands, respectively. If we insert the Bloch function in the l.h.s of Eq. (1), we alternatively have:
$$\tag{2}
\begin{align}
\langle \psi_{c\mathbf{k}}|\partial_\mathbf{k} \psi_{v\mathbf{k}}\rangle &=
\langle u_{c\mathbf{k}}|e^{-i\mathbf{k \cdot r}}\partial_\mathbf{k} (u_{v\mathbf{k}}e^{i\mathbf{k \cdot r}}) \rangle \\ \tag{3}&= \langle u_{c\mathbf{k}}|e^{-i\mathbf{k \cdot r}}(\partial_\mathbf{k} u_{v\mathbf{k}}e^{i\mathbf{k \cdot r}}+i\mathbf{r}e^{i\mathbf{k \cdot r}}u_{v\mathbf{k}}) \rangle \\&= \langle u_{c\mathbf{k}}|\partial_\mathbf{k} u_{v\mathbf{k}}\rangle + i \langle u_{c\mathbf{k}}|\mathbf{r}| u_{v\mathbf{k}}\rangle = 0 \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
So we get a different answer for the same initial braket. I believe there is something wrong with the second equation. Any idea?

Comment: could you provide more information?

Comment: I'm sorry but what else information do you need?

Comment: Can you give any references or links to the perturbation theory you are referring to? Some background for the setup and what the terms in the above equations specify?

Comment: The $\mathbf{k \cdot p}$ perturbation theory can be found at wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C2%B7p_perturbation_theory. Also please refer to Eq. 41 of https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0217979211058912. The matrix elements are used to calculate the optical properties.

Comment: The background is doing DFT calculations of periodic solids.

Comment: I think the "trick" is incorrect. I have seen $r\to-i\exp(ik\cdot r)\nabla_k\exp(-ik\cdot r)$, but not without the the exponentials being explicitly included in the transformation.

Comment: @Tyberius Yes, I just realized the first equal sign of Eq (1) is wrong. The use of the trick is indeed very limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding my comment to an answer, I believe the "trick" is incorrect.

As far as I'm aware, the relationship between $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $\boldsymbol{\nabla_k}$ is $$\boldsymbol{r}\to-i\exp(i\boldsymbol{k}\cdot \boldsymbol{r})\boldsymbol{\nabla_k}\exp(-i\boldsymbol{k}\cdot \boldsymbol{r})$$

This would mean at least the middle equality of equation [\ref{1}] is incorrect.